# Update push message with new text

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Is there any way to update text of a push notification after the message delivered to phone and user not accessed the notification with in some specific time.

Answer (score 1):

From **iOS 10** on you can update the content (e.g title and body) of a notification within a *NotificationSerivceExtension*.

Note: the payload must contain the key `mutable-content` with value `1`.

See Apples Documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationserviceextension

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to update an already sent message. The message in the notification center on lock screen can't be changed.

You could pass extra info through the push payload like time sent and a secondary message. If when the message is pressed, your app opens and if time lapse is greater than X you could display the secondary message from the payload.

Some info about payloads can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW1) (under the payload notification section) or [here.](https://docs.pushio.com/API_&_cURL_Information/Platform_Specific_Payloads/APNS_(Apple_Push_Notification_Service))